# İn what context did Lord of the Flies get mentioned in "Ape and Essence"?

Tags: aldous-huxley, anthony-burgess, ape-and-essence, nineteen-eighty-five

> Look at the literature that came out of the late forties and the
> fifties. Take Aldous Huxley’s *Ape and Essence* with its picture of
> post-Bomb Southern California reverted to savagery, with mutated
> freaks killed at birth, seasonal sex, the Lord of the Flies,
> Bomb-bringer, appeased with prayers and sacrifice
>
> 1985 by Anthony Burgess

Anthony Burgess gives examples of literature of late forties and fifties. The first example is *Ape and Essence* then he talks a little about the content of this book.

I want to know what does "the Lord of the Flies" and "Bomb-bringer" mean in this context. I tried to search for them inside *Ape and Essence* but couldn't make any sense of it. Although the name "Lord of  Flies" is mentioned in *Ape and Essence*, there is nothing like "Bomb-bringer" in that book.

Comment: @MattThrower Burgess was not referring to the novel by William Golding! (Though probably the name of the novel was the cause of the mistake: *Ape and Essence* always uses "Lord of Flies", not "Lord of *the* Flies" as claimed by Burgess.)

Comment: @GarethRees Ah right. So Burgess essentially misquoted it in 1985?

Comment: Yes, he was probably working from memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: Burgess was probably relying on his memory of [*Ape and Essence*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ape_and_Essence) when writing the introduction to *1985*, so that not all the details are correct.

The reason that I think Burgess was relying on his memory rather than consulting the text directly, is that he uses the phrase “Lord of the Flies” as an epithet for the being “appeased with prayers and sacrifice” by the post-apocalyptic inhabitants of California in Huxley’s novel. But in the text of the novel, the epithet is always “Lord of Flies”, with no “the”:

> “Such,” he squeaks unctuously, “is the inscrutable justice of the **Lord of Flies**.” ([p. 95](https://archive.org/details/apeessencenovel0000unse/page/94/mode/2up))
>
> Of the great Blowfly who is the **Lord of Flies** ([p. 109](https://archive.org/details/apeessencenovel0000unse/page/108/mode/2up))
>
> “With more and more of the human race falling into line behind him, the **Lord of Flies**, who is also the Blowfly in every individual heart” ([p. 120](https://archive.org/details/apeessencenovel0000unse/page/120/mode/2up))
>
> <sub>Aldous Huxley (1948). *Ape and Essence*. New York: Harper and Brothers</sub>

It seems that Burgess had forgotten the exact phrasing in *Ape and Essence* and substituted the more common “Lord of the Flies”, an epithet of the Philistine god [Beelzebub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beelzebub), and the name of a [famous 1954 novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord_of_the_Flies) by William Golding.

So if Burgess could make one mistake through fallibility of memory, he could make another, and I suspect that’s where the “Bomb-bringer” idea comes from. In *Ape and Essence*, Belial is associated with the bomb, but not imagined as responsible for bringing it:

> “If they’d stuck to the personal and the universal, they’d have been in harmony with the Order of Things, and the Lord of Flies would have been done for. But fortunately Belial had plenty of allies—the nations, the churches, the political parties. He used their prejudices. He exploited their ideologies. By the time they’d developed the atomic bomb, he had people back in the state of mind they were in before 900 B.C.”
>
> <sub>[Huxley, p. 184](https://archive.org/details/apeessencenovel0000unse/page/184/mode/2up).</sub>

This exaggeration of the connection between Belial and the bomb in *Ape and Essence* could have happened through confusion with elements of other works of speculative fiction with similar scenarios. In particular, *Ape and Essence* shares plot elements, including intelligent apes and a cult of post-apocalyptic survivors, with the 1970 film [*Beneath the Planet of the Apes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beneath_the_Planet_of_the_Apes). However, in the film, the cultists worship, not Belial as in Huxley, but the “Divine Bomb”:

> **Brent** Your God—what a joke! You worship something we made two thousand years ago! an Atom Bomb!
>
> <sub>Paul Dehn (1969). Screenplay for *Beneath the Planet of the Apes*.</sub>

Comment: "Bomb-bringer" may also be an echo of Lucifer, "Light-bringer", in Christian mythology often regarded as a senior demon alongside Belial, Beelzebub and others

Comment: @alexg: It's a good epithet—unsurprisingly, since Burgess was a talented and imaginative writer.